# Why am I getting nothing back from my Firestore request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to work with Firebase for the first time. I've set up the Firestore emulator and have put data in that I would like to retrieve in my Nextjs app. After initializing firebase, this is what my component looks like:

```
function Test() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const db = getFirestore();
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);

    async function testFirestore() {
      const testRef = doc(db, "test", "testid");
      const testSnap = await getDoc(testRef);
      console.log("does not reach this line")
      console.log(testSnap.data());
    }
    testFirestore();
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}

export default Test;
```

The problem is that I am getting nothing logged to the console. Not an error message, just nothing. The testFirestore function is running, but is seems to not get past the await getDoc() line. I also am not seeing requests coming in on the Firestore emulator. What am I doing wrong? I am sorry that I cannot be more specific, but there's no errors so it's hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: Upgrading solved it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue in Firebase JS SDK as mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5402). Upgrading to latest version should fix that issue.